# List does not exist: sharepoint

Tags: php, sharepoint

I want to fetch a video from SharePoint and am using this [API](https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API). It actually asks for WSDL file. I got `WSDL` file from this link https://mysite.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL (Replacing `mysite` with actual URL for security reasons). I am using the code below

```
    <?php
include "src\Thybag\SharePointAPI.php";
include "src\Thybag\Auth\SharePointOnlineAuth.php";
include "src\Thybag\Auth\SoapClientAuth.php";
include "src\Thybag\Auth\StreamWrapperHttpAuth.php";
include "src\Thybag\Service\ListService.php";
include "src\Thybag\Service\QueryObjectService.php";
use Thybag\SharePointAPI;
$sp = new SharePointAPI('username','password',' https://mysite.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL','SPONLINE');
$data = $sp->read('Documents');
var_dump($data);

//phpinfo();
?>
```

I am following this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Error (soap:Server) Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.,more=Detailed: List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user. in C:\xampp\htdocs\sharepoint\src\Thybag\SharePointAPI.php:1016 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sharepoint\src\Thybag\SharePointAPI.php(446): Thybag\SharePointAPI->onError(Object(SoapFault)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\sharepoint\zain.php(10): Thybag\SharePointAPI->read('Documents') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sharepoint\src\Thybag\SharePointAPI.php on line 1016

It actually says that `List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.` which I have really no idea that how to deal with this. I actually don't know that how to make new WSDL file in Sharepoint

If I use these credentials

```
$sp = new SharePointAPI('username','password','https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/ObjectifiedWIP/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL');
```

then It gives me this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Error (HTTP) Forbidden,more= in C:\xampp\htdocs\sharepoint\src\Thybag\SharePointAPI.php:1016 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sharepoint\src\Thybag\SharePointAPI.php(446): Thybag\SharePointAPI->onError(Object(SoapFault)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\sharepoint\zain.php(10): Thybag\SharePointAPI->read('Documents') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sharepoint\src\Thybag\SharePointAPI.php on line 1016

I really don't know that how to tackle them. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that 'Documents' is a valid list name for the given url?

Comment: You are accessing root site collection of web application which out-of-the-box does not contain "Documents" library. If you created it manualy try to check if the display name is the same in all enabled languages.

Comment: I have moved to another project. On returning back I will reply back all of you guys